# warning in ./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#856

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to show all records in phpmyadmin, phpmyadmin givin warning ./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#856.

i am using mariDb 10 Database connection with phpmyadmin in Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

- You can solve this problem

1. step - Open Terminal (Ctl + Alt + T);
2. Step - `cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries`
3. step - `sudo nano DisplayResults.class.php`
4. step - find

- `// Move to the next page or to the last one $endpos = $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos'] + $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'];`

5. step - replace it with
   `$endpos = 0; if (!empty($_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']) &&  is_numeric($_SESSION['tmpval']['pos'])) { $endpos += $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']; } if (!empty($_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows']) &&  is_numeric($_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'])) { $endpos += $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows']; }`
6. step -  Save file and close terminal
   Your problem is solved now please restart phpmyadmin

Thanks

- Sonu Rajput